# Sorting a hash of hash by second levels keys in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash as follows:

```
          '4' => {
                   '25' => 'X',
                   '24' => 'Y',
                   '23' => 'Z'
                 },
          '3' => {
                   '22' => 'S',
                   '15' => 'T'
                 },
          '2' => {
                   '11' => 'A',
                   '21' => 'B',
                   '9' => 'C',
                   '17' => 'D',
                   '12' => 'E',
                   '20' => 'F',
                   '14' => 'G',
                   '4' => 'H',
                   '18' => 'I',
                   '19' => 'J',
                   '16' => 'K',
                   '10' => 'L',
                   '13' => 'M'
                 }
```

I want to sort first on the basis of primary key or the first key that is 2,3,4. Then for each of the key, say for 4, I want to sort for secondary key so, the expected output will be:

```
          '4' => {
                   '23' => 'Z',
                   '24' => 'Y',
                   '25' => 'X'


                 },
          '3' => {
                   '15' => 'T',
                   '22' => 'S'

                 },
          '2' => {
                   '4' => 'H',
                   '9' => 'C',
                   '10' => 'L',
                   '11' => 'A',
                   '12' => 'E',
                   '13' => 'M',
                   '14' => 'G',
                   '16' => 'K',
                   '17' => 'D',
                   '18' => 'I',
                   '19' => 'J',
                   '20' => 'F',
                   '21' => 'B'
                 }
```

I tried this code, but the secondary keys are not getting sorted:

```
foreach $parentKey (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %orderedChoiceNameHash) {
    for $childKey (sort {$orderedChoiceNameHash{$a} <=> $orderedChoiceNameHash{$b}} keys %{ $orderedChoiceNameHash{$parentKey}}) {
        print $fh "$parentKey ::::: $childKey ::::: $orderedChoiceNameHash{$parentKey}{$childKey}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please show us what you tried, your code?  Here people normally post questions about specific problems that they have with their code.  It is not a place where one simply asks for code to be written for them.

Comment: foreach $parentKey (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %orderedChoiceNameHash) {
 for $childKey (sort {$orderedChoiceNameHash{$a} <=> $orderedChoiceNameHash{$b}} keys %{ $orderedChoiceNameHash{$parentKey}}) {
     print $fh "$parentKey ::::: $childKey :::::  $orderedChoiceNameHash{$parentKey}{$childKey}\n";
 }
}

Comment: The above is the code I tried. But the secondary keys are not getting sorted.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code you've tried there so it's easily visible.

Comment: Can't sort a hash.  What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @ikegami He wants to print the hash out in a sorted order.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach my $key1 (sort {$b<=>$a} keys %hash)
{
    foreach my $key2 (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %{ $hash{$key1} })
    {
        print "$key1\t$key2\t$hash{$key1}{$key2}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: output of the above code will be like first key sorted in descending order ($b<=>$a) and second key sorted in ascending order ($a<=>$b). If you want first key to sort in ascending order just use $a<=>$b.